# How to use rbind with SPDFs when the number of columns of arguments do not match?

Tags: r, sp

I'm looking to use `rbind` to combine the SPDFs of different European countries. However, I'm looking to use SPDFs of different levels of regions. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

France_map <- getData(name = "GADM", country = "FRA", level = 0)
Germany_map <- getData(name = "GADM", country = "DEU", level = 1)
Belgium_map <- getData(name = "GADM", country = "BEL", level = 2)

test <- rbind(France_map, Germany_map, Belgium_map, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)

Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

How do I need to treat the individual SPDFs so that they can be bound together?

Comment: dplyr::bind_rows() works for the SPDF@data not having the same columns, but not for the whole SPDF, you may try to do that as two separate tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes/columns in each dataframe are completely different, but if you want to bind with `rbind` they need to match.

Is there a reason for the different administrative levels? If you were to use (e.g.) `level=1` for each country, the attributes would match and the `rbind` will work as intended.

If you need to keep the specified levels, then you'll need to reduce and harmonise the attributes/columns before attempting the `rbind`.

Comment: Thanks Jul. I have since manually harmonized the columns across the SPDFs, and they now work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no actual need for a two-step approach when trying to combine the single objects in such a way that all columns are kept (ie. missing columns are filled with `NA`). In fact, this can be achieved in one go using `bind()` from **raster**:

```
out1 = bind(France_map, Germany_map, Belgium_map)

# or, when dealing with lists (eg. resulting from some *apply call),
countries = list(France_map, Germany_map, Belgium_map)
out2 = do.call(bind, countries)
```